# Ruby on Rails - Assign View and/or edit to different users (in same team)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, assign

In my application I have models `Team` `User` `Post`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :team

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

*In my `_form.html.haml` I have this part:*

```
- User.where(team_id: current_user.team_id).each do |user|
  %p=user.name
```

*Which shows all users in same team.*

When a **user** *(In the same team)* writes a `post`. I want them to be able to assign users who can **Edit** and/or **View** the post.

*This means user can assign some users to only **View** and some to **View & Edit**.*

How can I do this and whats the best way to go forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create another model, might look like this:

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :permissions
  belongs_to :team

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: permissions
  belongs_to :user
```

Permission model might have fields such as "id", "post_id", "user_id", "editable" and "viewable" (last 2 fields as boolean).  When you submit, you can create as many permission roles as selected by the user for the post.  You would then only allow people to edit if @user.post.permission == post.user_id && @user.permission.editable? both come back as true (or something like that, not sure exactly how the rest of your app is set-up)

Comment: Thanks @Michael. And in my `posts#_form.html.haml` I also add a separate `form` for  `permissions` Or I can do the assignment in the same `form`, if so how?

Comment: What you're referring to are nested forms.  Check out section 9 (nested forms) of the rails guides:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms.  Lots of good references on stackoverflow for nested forms as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance method and use it

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :team

  def team_members
    User.where(team_id: team_id)

    # If you dont want current_user/self in the result you can use
    # User.where(team_id: team_id).where.not(id: id) 
  end
end
```

And now you can use it

```
- current_user.team_members.each do |user|
```

Also, you can use it in dropdown

```
= f.collection_select :user_id, current_user.team_members, :id, :name
```

**Q. How can I assign View and/or Edit & View for the post to each user in same team?**

A. You can check if the current user belongs to the team of the post author

Something like

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  - if post.user.team_members.include?(current_user)
    = link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post)
```

Comment: Thanks @Deepak. This just gets/shows the `users` right? How can I assign **View** and/or **Edit & View** for the *post* to each user in same team?